# Problem with a validator used with JSF

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I'am using JSF2.0

I have used a validator that valid an input text ,but no msg appear to indicate that the input is wrong!

**Update:**

Are Their a way that validate inputtext before submitting ,just after typing the inputText?

**The JSF code:**

```
 <h:form id="form3">
      <p:panel visible="#{bean.form3Visible}" style="width: 900px;">
         <h:panelGrid width="width: 900px;"    columns="1">
         <p /> 
               <h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.platform}">
                 <f:selectItem itemLabel="-- Select Plateform-- " itemValue="0"/> 
                 <f:selectItems value="#{bean.getMyListPaltform()}" />
                 <f:ajax listener="#{bean.UpdateChangeEnvironment()}"  render="Environment" />
                </h:selectOneMenu>
             


<h:panelGrid width="width: 160px;" columns="9">                                           
 <h:inputText id="ssFrom" value="#{bean.ssFrom}" required="true"  style="width: 18px" >    <f:validateLongRange   minimum="0" maximum="24"/>
 </h:inputText>
 <h:message  for="ssFrom" id="msgg" style="color:red" />
    </h:panelGrid>                                                                                       
      </p:panel>    
   </h:form>
```

**I have solved my problem this is the answer perhaps it can help others :**

```
      <h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.availabilityDisplay}" id="Display">
          <f:selectItem itemLabel="-- Select Display-- " itemValue="0"/> 
          <f:selectItems value="#{bean.getMyListDisplays()}"/>
          <f:ajax render="Target" />
      </h:selectOneMenu>
         
            
    <p:outputPanel id="Target">
      <h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.frequency}" id="frequency" rendered="#{bean.availabilityDisplay == 'Availibility Histogramme' or bean.availabilityDisplay == 'Availibility line'}">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="-- Select Frequency-- " itemValue="0"/>
        <f:selectItems  value="#{bean.getMyListFrequency()}"/>
     </h:selectOneMenu>
   </p:outputPanel>
```

Thank you

Comment: I formatted your XML as you should always do. Now you can see that there is no end tag for the `<h:panelGrid` in line 3.

Comment: Please post another question regarding the input validation on client side.

Comment: You should not mix different problems/questions in a single question. Post each independent problem/question in its own question.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add either a `h:message` oder a `h:messages` tag to display the error message.

```
<h:inputText value="#{bean.ssFrom}" required="true" style="width: 18px" id="ssFrom"> 
    <f:validateLongRange minimum="0" maximum="59"/>
</h:inputText>

<h:message for="ssFrom" />
<!-- OR -->
<h:messages />
```

`h:message` is used to display errors for a single field (connected by the `for` attribute). `h:messages` can be used to display all error messages of the page. If you set `globalOnly="true"`, it will display only messages that are not "caught" by a `h:message` tag.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply ,I have tried to add ::message but nothing happened!! and I have an another question ,the validator will valid the input text after typing the text or after submitting the form? because I want to validate the text before submitting the form

Comment: @rym The validator will validate after submitting the form. Please append your current code snippet to your question.

Comment: Please add a closing `</h:panelGrid>` as mentioned above (edits) and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please paste the whole page code.

However possible problems may be:

- You haven't used a h:message or h:messages tag in the page. Messages are only shown if anyone of these is used in the page
- Or your text field may not be enclosed with in a h:form
- Also note that range validators are not triggered when the text field is left empty.
- For useful messages, use `requiredMessage="whatever" validatorMessage="whatever"` attributes in the text field

Answer (score 1):

In order to validate `<h:inputText>` without submitting the form, you need to add ajax capabilities.

```
<h:inputText id="ssFrom" value="#{bean.ssFrom}" required="true"  style="width: 18px" >    
<f:validateLongRange   minimum="0" maximum="24"/>
<f:ajax execute="@this" event="keyup"/>
</h:inputText>
```

The `f:ajax` tag will update your `ssForm` variable on every key up event and if a validation error occurs, it will be displayed in the `<h:message for="ssFrom" />` as Mulmoth said.